# How to ignore password protected excel sheets programmatically

Tags: vb.net, excel

With my Tool we are scanning excel files and generating reports. My problem is some excel sheets are password protected and getting pup-up while scanning and it halts the Tool to run further.

Could someone let me know the solution, how to overcome with this problem. I just need to skip the sheet and continue with scanning without any user intervention.

Thank You,

Sugam

Answer (score 1):

The workbook has a HasPassword property i.e. (C#):

```
Workbook book = GetYourWorkbook();
if (book.HasPassword)
{
  // Ignore!
}
else
{
  // Perform your operations here
}
```